# How can I make a CSS grid fill the height of the parent element?

Tags: css, css-grid

I wish to make a button, using CSS grid, with the elements filling the full height of the container:

```css
button {
  display: grid;
  height: 50px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.one {
  color: white;
  background-color: purple;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <span class="one">one</span>
  <span class="two">two</span>
</button>
```

As one can see from the inspector, this is a single row, that doesn't fill the height of the container:

[image]

I'd like the grid to fill the container, so the whole left of the container is purple.

Comment: please don't stop at the title of the duplicate, read it to see that the issue is the same.

Comment: @TemaniAfif sure & done. It's not a duplicate.

Comment: The original wording of the target was misleading, but it was in fact a duplicate. It has been edited for clarity and should be more clear now. I've also added a second dupe target that explains why inline elements don't take the full height of the container and how to make them do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with `height: 100%;` on any of the items inside the grid

**Working example:**

```css
button {
  display: grid;
  height: 50px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.one {
  color: white;
  background-color: purple;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <span class="one">one</span>
  <span class="two">two</span>
</button>
```

---

If you want the text centered verticaly you can use `display: grid` or `display: inline-grid` and `align-items: center`.

**Working example:**

```css
button {
  display: grid;
  height: 50px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.one {
  color: white;
  background-color: purple;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  display: grid;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <span class="one">one</span>
  <span class="two">two</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to keep centering the text with `grid` rather than changing to `inline-flex`?

Comment: Yes, with ```display: grid``` - i changed the answer...

Answer (score 1):

```css
button {
  display: grid;
  height: 50px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.one {
  color: white;
  background-color: purple;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
}

span {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <span class="one">one</span>
  <span class="two">two</span>
</button>
```

Comment: This is good but seems the same as the existing answer.